# sending html email in perl not working

Tags: perl

Below is the perl code I used to send HTML email:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use IO::File;

my $score = 2;
my $to = 'abc@a.com';
my $from = 'def@b.com';
my $subject = "SHV summary report for servers with score $score or higher";
my $mailbody = '<html><body>Hello</body></html>';
open(MAIL,"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    print MAIL "To: $to\n";
    print MAIL "From: $from\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
    print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"
        . "$mailbody";

close(MAIL);
```

It's not working. I receives no email.
But if I replace the open () call with:

open(MAIL,"|cat -t");

It prints the following:

```
To: abc@a.com
From: def@b.com
Subject: SHV summary report for servers with score 2 or higher
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>Hello</body></html>
```

if I replace:

```
my $subject = "SHV summary report for servers with score $score or higher";
```

with:

```
my $subject = "SHV summary report for servers with core $score";
```

then everything work fine. If I

change "core" back to "score", or

add "or higher" to the string, or

change it to "SHV score $score or higher"

it stop working. Anyone knows why?

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: Does /usr/sbin/sendmail send mail when you're not using Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use operating system commands when Perl has more Perlish solutions

You cannot depend upon operating systems commands working from system to system, and you cannot depend upon them actually being configured.

[Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) is included in Perl since 5.8.8. It doesn't depend upon `sendmail` being configured, and it usually works. I've used it over and over again in many of my programs. I have never used it for MIME message handling. But, it looks like you're doing the MIME bit manually anyway, so `Net::SMTP` should work.

However, the FAQ in Perl has a [How do I use MIME to make an attachment to a mail message](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-use-MIME-to-make-an-attachment-to-a-mail-message%3f) that points to the [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aMIME) module. This doesn't come part of standard Perl, but shouldn't be too difficult to install.

Answer (score 1):

change it to :

```
open( MAIL, qq(| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t abc\@a.com)) or die "failed on sending email ";
print MAIL "From:$from\n";
print MAIL "To:$to\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"
print MAIL "\n$mailbody";
```

Comment: @user2723438 add -tv to get some debugging info

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated information, it sounds like Sendmail is configured to reject messages with a too-long subject line.  However, people don't like using Sendmail much these days, partly because it's configuration is hard to work out and partly because it was riddled with security errors.

It may be possible to solve the subject line problem, but I don't know enough about Sendmail configuration to help you.  You could try switching to something like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) or [QMail](http://cr.yp.to/qmail.html), but I would recommend just using a module.  I have no experience with it, but [Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSMTP) looks promising (you need a mail server set up to use Net::SMTP, which in your case could be 'localhost', assuming you continue to run Sendmail or another mail server program on the same system as the Perl script).

Comment: /usr/bin/sendmail may very well be a front end for qmail or postfix, rather than real Sendmail

Comment: It seems that this is not the case. coz if I use: my $subject = "SHV score $score or highe"; it still won't work.

Comment: Even so, I'd discourage spending any time on configuring Sendmail and instead move to a module like Net::SMTP (See David W.'s answer).

Comment: There must be something magic about the word "score" in a subject line.

Answer (score 0):

Mail::SendEasy should be a quick and easy alternative solution.

It supports HTML Email, SMTP authentication, attachments, etc. With Mail::SendEasy you can also cut out the use of the sendmail program. So in the event where the sendmail program has issues or problems this will normally be automatically solved when using Mail::SendEasy

[You can find out more about it at here.](http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/Mail-SendEasy-1.2/lib/Mail/SendEasy.pm)